# creating nested Async tasks android

Tags: multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm developing an android application where I connect to a server to get data
I'm using Volley library to perform my request in a separate class from the controller class, I put the data from the server in global list where I call it from the UI thread
my problem is when I call the function that initiates the call to the server it starts the Async task for the connection and doesn't wait for the data and calls the function that adds the data to the UI
so can I put the call of the function that initiates the call in an Async task and have nested Async tasks or it will do the same

Comment: Please post some relevant code please

Answer (score 0):

```
new AsynctaskName().execute().get();
```

Try using get() to execute async task.
It will wait until the async task get executed.